# Table of Contents is not jumping for the next page

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, elsarticle

The table of contents is not jumping for the next page. It keep going indefinitely in the first page. I'm using the `elsarticle` template. Does anybody knows how to make the table jump to the next page?

[image: Here is the example. The table of contents goes through the footer and beyond.]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You should definitely tell us the document class options you've set for your particular document. Also, is it really true that all nine sections of the document fit on a single page (page 2 according to your screenshot)?

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**
Looks like you are using `elsarticle` with option `twocolumn` and given `\tableofcontents` inside `keyword` environment.

**Solution**
Just move `\tableofcontents` after `\end{frontmatter}` and try.  That will solve the problem.